# Set of subsequential limit - Trying to finish a proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to answer this proof:

[set of subsequential limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538289/set-of-subsequential-limit)

I followed the int that was given, so I made  $\varepsilon := \dfrac{\min\{|c-a|, |c-b|\}}{2}$

Then, individually I tried to solve $ c - \varepsilon < x_n <c + \varepsilon $ making $\varepsilon := \dfrac{{|c-a|}}{2}$ and $\varepsilon := \dfrac{{|c-b|}}{2}$

And I reached that $ |b|< c $ and $ |a|< c $

But now how can I conclude what I want to prove... Can someone give a hint? Or am I proving this wrongly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the proof that you have linked to is that you choose a value $c \neq a, b$ and show that it cannot be a subsequential limit.

We have $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}{x_{2k}} = a$, implies for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_{a} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for for all $n \geq N_{a}$, $|x_{2n} - a| < \epsilon$

Similarly by $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}{x_{2k + 1}} = b$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have an $N_{b} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N_{b}$, $|x_{2n + 1} - b| < \epsilon$

The point of the hint you refer to is that, if we take $\epsilon \leq \displaystyle\min\left\{\cfrac{|a - c|}{2}, \cfrac{|b - c|}{2}\right\}$ and let $N = \displaystyle\max\left\{N_{a}, N_{b}\right\}$ then both subsequences, $\left(x_{2k}\right)_{k}$ and $\left(x_{2k + 1}\right)_{k}$ remain in the union of intervals $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \cup (b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ for all $n \geq N$.

Then, because of how we chose $\epsilon$, $c$ is not in this union of intervals and therefore cannot be in the set of subsequential limits.

Comment: If you're struggling with the idea, define a sequence that is equal to $1$ for every odd subscript and $0$ for every even subscript, so that $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, for example. Then pick some easy to compute with $c$, and try and follow the argument and actually draw the union of open sets on an $\mathbb{R}$-line.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. i still don't get how choosing you get do that union of intervals... And how does that apply to c... I mean how do we reach there and know that c is not in that union of intervals?

Comment: For $n \geq N_{a}$ we have $|x_{2n} - a| < \epsilon$ which is equivalent to saying $x_{2n} \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$.

Similarly for $n \geq N_{b}$ we have $|x_{2n + 1} - b | < \epsilon$ which is equivalent to $x_{2n + 1} \in (b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$.

If $n \geq N = \displaystyle\max\left\{N_{a}, N_{b}\right\}$ then both conditions are satisfied so all the even subscripts greater equal $N$ are in the interval $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ and all the odd subscripts greater equal $N$ are in $(b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$. Hence all subscripts greater equal $N$ are in the union.

Comment: Then in words, we pick $\epsilon$ such that it is smaller than both half the distance between $a$ and $c$ and half the distance between $b$ and $c$. Then $c$ will be in neither of these open intervals, and therefore not in their union.